# PHP add GET variable to links

Tags: php, variables, get

I have a page with links that looks like this:

```
<a href="http://mysite.com/page.php">...</a>
```

I also may have a GET variable **?lang=en** in the current url. How can I add the GET variable ?lang=en to all the links from the page, without adding them manually or adding a variable to each link? Thanks.

Comment: Define "I have a page". It sounds like a static page, is it one?

Comment: You should write a function/method to generate the URL.

Answer (score 0):

set `$_ENV['lang'] = 'en'` in your basic ( assume **config.php** ) file

and retrieve by 
`getenv('lang')` or `$_ENV['lang']`

[`Refernece`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.environment.php)

Answer (score 0):

Add **lang=en** to session variable as `$_SESSION['lang']='en'` & initialized it in every page.

Answer (score 0):

You could use output buffering or an Apache filter to parse your output to automatically add the lang query string parameter to all links, however, this isn't terribly efficient.

If you really do not want to add it manually to each link then I suggest you store it in a session variable.

At the start of each page (perhaps in a generic include script) you could have something like:

```
<?php
define('DEFAULT_LANG', 'en_GB');

session_start();

// check if a new lang has been specified.
if (isset($_GET['lang'])) {

    // yes, so use the requested lang
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $_GET['lang'];

    // otherwise, check if a lang was previously set
} else if ( ! isset($_SESSION['lang']) ) {

    // no, so use default lang:
    $_SESSION['lang'] = DEFAULT_LANG;

}
?>
```

You should then use `$_SESSION['lang']` instead of `$_GET['lang']` in the rest of your page.  Also, you may want to add some sort of validation to ensure the requested lang is valid and available.

Comment: Change `} else if ( ! isset($_SESSION['lang']) ) {` to `} else {` ... PHP don't need to check again to see if !isset

Comment: No - the first `isset` checks if `$_GET['lang']`, the second `$_SESSION['lang']`.  Read the comments.

Comment: Oups I tought it was both $_GET, sorry :S